# iPad app modalpopup view corner not get proper color...?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uicolor, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm developing iPad application, at some point I need to popup view on IBAction. And the same I done properly with below code.

```
SCSelection *vcSCSelection = [[SCSelection alloc]initWithNibName:@"SCSelection" bundle:Nil];
vcSCSelection.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:vcSCSelection animated:YES];
```

It's work properly and shows me my view which size is **Form Sheet**.
I need some Background custom color apply on this view, and which I maintain in popup view's **- (void)viewDidLoad** method as below.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61/255.0 green:61/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Now, my issue is when popup view shown It's covered with background color apply on it,except it's corner as below. As you can find that there is some corner space where color effect are not apply. I just highlight it with oval.
[image]
How can I overcome from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and here's a quick write up with comments on how I did it. Note, this code is in the view controller which triggers the modal view presentation.

```
    // Login Table View Controller
    UITableViewController *loginPanel = (UITableViewController*)  [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LoginTVC"];

    // Setup Login panel presentation style
    loginPanel.modalPresentationStyle               = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    // Present Login Panel (called before view's bounds modifications so that it instantiates
    [self presentViewController:loginPanel animated:YES completion:nil];

    // ============================================
    // Make form sheet's view slightly smaller or
    // equal to the login panel's view so that corners
    // don't have white color bleed.
    // ============================================

    // Set the bounds & clipping (very important) of the
    // superview (which would be the formsheet's view
    // when using UIModalPresentationFormSheet)
    loginPanel.view.superview.bounds                = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 380);
    loginPanel.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius    = 8.0f; 
    loginPanel.view.superview.clipsToBounds         = YES;

    // Set the bounds of the view being presented modally as UIModalPresentationFormSheet 
    loginPanel.view.bounds                          = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 380);
```